# How can I parse table data from website using Selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, parsing, web-scraping

Im trying to parse the table present in the  [website][1]

[1]: http://www.espncricinfo.com/rankings/content/page/211270.html using selenium, as I am beginner . i'm struggling to do that here is my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium import webdriver

url = "http://www.espncricinfo.com/rankings/content/page/211270.html"
browser = webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

print(len(soup.find_all("table")))
print(soup.find("table", {"class": "expanded_standings"}))

browser.close()
browser.quit()
```

that I tried, I'm unable to fetch anything from this, any suggestions will be really helpful thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table you are after is within an `iframe`. So, to get the data from that table you need to switch that `iframe` first and then do the rest. Here is one way you could do it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.espncricinfo.com/rankings/content/page/211270.html")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
 ## if any different table you expect to have then just change the index number within nth-of-type()
 ## and the appropriate name in the selector
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[name='testbat']:nth-of-type(1)")))
for table in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table tr")))[1:]:
    data = [item.text for item in table.find_elements_by_css_selector("th,td")]
    print(data)
driver.quit()
```

And the best approach would be in this very case is as follows. No browser simulator is used. Only `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` have been used:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get("http://www.espncricinfo.com/rankings/content/page/211270.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
 ## if any different table you expect to have then just change the index number 
 ## and the appropriate name in the selector
item = soup.select("iframe[name='testbat']")[0]['src']
req = requests.get(item)
sauce = BeautifulSoup(req.text,"lxml")
for items in sauce.select("table tr"):
    data = [item.text for item in items.select("th,td")]
    print(data)
```

Partial results:

```
['Rank', 'Name', 'Country', 'Rating']
['1', 'S.P.D. Smith', 'AUS', '947']
['2', 'V. Kohli', 'IND', '912']
['3', 'J.E. Root', 'ENG', '881']
```

Comment: How can I do for other tables in the page they all contain same frame name? I tried to call with different attribute I got error saying No such frame, using selenium method.

Comment: I just updated my post describing what to do. If anything still unclear do ask. You can reach every table from that page now. Just change the parameter according to your need.

Comment: If i try to scrap other tables , they all contain same frame name, I can't use href which is unique for each table, it gives me syntax error, I can do this using only beautiful soup method but can we do it using selenium?

Comment: You can change like these in selenium selectors `iframe[name='testbat']:nth-of-type(1)` or
`iframe[name='testbat']:nth-of-type(2)` or
`iframe[name='odibat']:nth-of-type(1)` or
`iframe[name='odibat']:nth-of-type(2)` and so on.

Comment: How can I get result in list of dictionary like [{'country': 'AUS', 'Rank': '1', 'Name': 'S.P.D. Smith', 'Rating': '947'}, {'country': 'IND', 'Rank': '2', 'Name': 'V. Kohli', 'Rating': '912'}, {'country': 'ENG', 'Rank': '3', 'Name': 'J.E. Root', 'Rating': '881'}  this? in bs4

Comment: I did it thanks for tr in sauce.find_all('tr'):
   count +=1
   tds = tr.find_all('td')
   if len(tds) > 0 :
    row = {'Rank':tds[0].text,'Name': tds[1].text, 'country' : tds[2].text, 'Rating': tds[3].text}

Comment: why am I getting out of range for this item = soup.select("iframe[name='odibat']")[9]['src']?

Comment: Because the last table index from that page shoud be `8` not `9`. However, if you start from the last then you can do something like `item = soup.select("iframe[name='odibat']")[-1]['src']`. See the change in the index.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that page's tables are within iframes. If you have a specific table you want to scrape, try inspecting it using browser dev tools (right click, inspect element in Chrome) and find the iframe element that is wrapping it. The iframe should have a `src` attribute that holds a url to the page that *actually* contains that table. You can then use a similar method to the one you tried but instead use the `src` url.

Selenium can also "jump into" an iframe if you know how to find the iframe in the page's source code. 
`frame = browser.find_element_by_id("the_iframe_id")
browser.switch_to.frame(frame)
html = browser.page_source` etc