# Parse HTML Tables in Python - Click on Link in Cell

Tags: python, selenium, html-table, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse an HTML table and individually click on each hyperlink in the third column (where it says href="javascript:showPayCheck). There are a ton of posts that show how to parse tables, but I can't find any that look like this table I am using:

```
<div class="screen-group-content">        
    <div class="checkview-checks">
        <table cellpadding="2px" class="asureTable" cellspacing="0px" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
            <tbody><tr class="trHeader">
                <td style="font-weight: bold;">Payment Date</td>
                <td style="font-weight: bold;">Payment Type</td>
                <td style="font-weight: bold;">Check/ACH</td>
                <td style="font-weight: bold;">View $</td>
            </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="cursor: default;">01/18/2019</td>
                        <td style="cursor: default;">Regular Check</td>
                        <td style="cursor: default;">ACH</td>
                        <td style="cursor: default;"><a href="javascript:showPayCheck(589, 3106, 'REG', 'D');" title="View Check Detail">$3,023.10</a></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td style="cursor: default;">01/04/2019</td>
                        <td style="cursor: default;">Regular Check</td>
                        <td style="cursor: default;">ACH</td>
                        <td style="cursor: default;"><a href="javascript:showPayCheck(588, 3106, 'REG', 'D');" title="View Check Detail">$3,141.80</a></td>
                    </tr>
        </tbody></table>
        </div>
</div>
```

I have tried using BeautifulSoup:

```
import BeautifulSoup as bSoup
soup = bSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
td_list = soup.findAll('td')
for td in td_list:
    print(td.text)
```

And I have tried Selenium:

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_name("td")
for elem in elems:
    print(elem.text)
    elem.click()
```

I get nothing from either. The XPath of the table is:

```
//*[@id="form1"]/div[3]/div/div/table
```

and I have tried getting the table by XPath:

```
table=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="form1"]/div[3]/div/div/table')
for elem in table:
    print(elem.text)
```

but I get the error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="form1"]/div[3]/div/div/table"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

----Edit
Sorry, I am not so good with HTML. Here is where the element is in the hierarchy, is it in an iFrame?
[image]

Comment: Could you provide the URL, please??

Comment: Check if the table is inside a frame/iframe element

Comment: URL is behind a login. Let me scrape the entire page.

Answer (score 1):

Your xpath can be more specific, would suggest you go with incremental approach, first try with:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="form1"]//div[@class="screen-group-content"]')
```

If above returns True

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="form1"]//div[@class="screen-group-content"]//table[@class="asureTable"]')
```

If above is true too; then you could get rows and data by index on above Xpath.
Also, do check for any frames in the upper hierarchy of the HTML snippet that has been attached in your post.

Comment: Thanks Pooja. I starting with your suggestion and figured out the table was no where to be found. It was in an iFrame. See my answer for details.

Comment: Yes, iframes are the answer when a straightforward xpath doesn't work... Glad could help.

Answer (score 0):

The table is in an iFrame. You have to select it. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48656659/how-can-i-parse-table-data-from-website-using-selenium), I edited the code as follows:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(eConds.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((wdBy.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[id='hr2oScreen']:nth-of-type(1)")))
for table in wait.until(eConds.presence_of_all_elements_located((wdBy.CSS_SELECTOR, "table tr")))[1:]:
    data = [item.text for item in table.find_elements_by_css_selector("th,td")]
    print(data)
```

Thanks Pooja for giving me pointers on how to determine the text wasn't there.

Answer (score -1):

did you have try using regular expressions?

Using **Selenium**:

```
import re
from selenium import webdriver

#n = webdriver.Firefox() or n.webdriver.Chrome()
n.get_url( your_url )

html_source_code = str(n.page_source)
# Using a regular expression
# The element that you want to fetch/collect
#    will be inside of the 'values' variable
values = re.findall( r'title=\"View Check Detail\"\>(.+)\</td>', html_source_code )
```

**Update:** If the content is inside of a **iframe**, using **selenium + Chrome driver** you can do this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome import options

o = options.Options()
o.headless = True

n = webdriver.Chrome(options=o)
n.get_url( your_url )
links = n.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
outer = [ e.get_attribute("src") for e in links]

# In the best case outer will be a list o strings,
# each outer's element contain the values of the src attribute. 
# Compute the correct element inside of outer

n.get_url(correct_outer_element) 
# This will make a 'new' html code.
# Create a new xpath and fetch the data!
```

Comment: Enable the '--headless' into the webdriver's options class and the web browser window will not be open

Comment: I tried Regex and it's not finding it. I have tried printing (print (elem.text)) all elements, but I am getting no results at all.

Comment: @SteveGon now i can understand what it is going on!. Can you see the html **iframe** tag? Well follow the **src** atributte, it is a link. Inside of that link will be another page that contain a script or javascript that create the entire html code, inside of the iframe tag. The **iframe** generate a html inside of a html, wear no? Actually i found html pages with that structure. Again, follow the **src** link inside of the **ifrma** and take a look of that new html code, it is probably you find a json syntax, use regex to fecth.

Comment: @SteveGon can you share the **src** link adders or the html code inside of the **src** link? Some times it is difficult fetch data into a iframe.

Comment: @SteveGon Also, if you download the entire html source code from **selenium** you will not found the **iframe** tag section. That is why you can not fetch any data using **regex** or the find selenium methods.